# FlatList Pull to refresh not working inside Interactable.View in Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have used FlatList inside Interactable (react-native-interactable) .View with Pull to Refresh feature. I used Interactable.View to intergrate drag action to open Navigation Menu Drawer.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                <Menu
                    onItemSelected={this.onItemSelected}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                />
                <Interactable.View
                    style={styles.interactable}
                    ref={component => this.interactableView = component}
                    horizontalOnly={true}
                    animatedNativeDriver={true}
                    snapPoints={[{ x: 0, y: 0, damping: 0.8 }, { x: SideMenuWidth, y: 0, damping: 0.8 }]}
                    boundaries={{ left: 0, right: SideMenuWidth, top: 0 }}
                    initialPosition={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    onSnap={this.onSnapInteractable}
                    startOnFront={true}
                >
                    <Home
                        ref={component => this.home = component}
                        onToggleBurger={this.toggleMenu}
                        navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                </Interactable.View>
                <Loading isLoading={this.props.isLogining} />
</View>
```

In Home:

```
   <FlatList
        style={{zIndex: 10}}
        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={this._refreshData}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        data={this.state.sections}
        getItem={(data, index) => data.get(index)}
        getItemCount={(data) => data.size}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        keyExtractor={this._getKeyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        ListEmptyComponent={this._renderEmpty}
        ListFooterComponent={footerView}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
    />
```

Pull to refresh feature working fine in iOS but in Android it's not working or hard to pull.

Have any suggest to solve this isssue?